# Repeating code with dictionary instance vs list instance

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am receiving data from an API which is either a dictionary or a list of dictionaries.

Now, I find myself repeating the same code for the list of dictionaries case but just adding a for loop. For example:

```
def func(response: Union[Dict, List[Dict]]):
   if isinstance(response, dict):
      code here
   elif isinstance(response, list):
      for i in response:
         code here
```

So I'm just copy & pasting the code inside the for loop from the first instance where the response is a dictionary.

Is this standard or is there a way I can stop repeating the same code?

Comment: what about calling a function that processes a dictionary either once if the input is dict or n times for n list elements? keep it dry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do that:

```py
def func(response: Union[Dict, List[Dict]]):
   to_process = response if isinstance(response, list) else [response]
   for i in to_process:
      code here
```